# Looking for Flash RTMP hosting without video support

Tags: flash, object, shared

I'm looking to create a flash game eviroment where a client's members can play each other in a realtime environment.  Mostly trivia question type things, and maybe some shared animations.  I've done this over RTMP before with a host that also provided video streaming, but I only need the Shared Object communications this time.

Does anybody know of a cheaper option that's focused on the Shared Object side of things?  Or does Shared Object communication take just as much resources as video to support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about setting up your own server for your purposes? Get a VPS from somewhere like Knownhost (http://www.knownhost.com/vps_packages.html - starts at $25/month) - install Red5 streaming server (open source with the same purpose as Adobe's Flash Media Server) http://www.sohailriaz.com/how-to-install-red5-server-on-centos-53/ - then voila - you're own streaming setup for $25/month with room to grow.